# Get value of Excel cell with the cell Address

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, spreadsheet, xlsx

I am trying to parse an Excel file using Apache POI version 3.17. And based on cell background color, I need to get value of cell before and after it (or some location in excel file). 
Code snippet:

```
    Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH)));
    Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
    for (Row row: sheet) {
        for(Cell cell: row) {
            String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
            XSSFCellStyle cellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)cell.getCellStyle();
            XSSFColor cellColor = cellStyle.getFillForegroundXSSFColor();
            if( cellColor != null && cellColor.getARGBHex().equals("FFCCFFCC") ){
                System.out.println(cellValue);
                System.out.println(cell.getAddress());
            }
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to get value of cell from sheet based on cell address. Something like:  sheet.getValueOfCell(cell.getAddress()).

Comment: It is not clear from your question what you are trying to achieve. The [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) knows [it's position in the row](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getColumnIndex--), it knows [it's row](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getRow--) and [it's sheet](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#getSheet--). So there should be many posibilities for getting other cells depending of this cell's position.

Comment: @AxelRichter Any one example of such possibilities is highly appreciated. I am not able to find any example to get cell value based on its position(cell address) in sheet.

Comment: `Cell cellbefore = cell.getRow().getCell(cell.getColumnIndex()-1);`

Comment: Thanks it worked. @AxelRichter